# Continuous function on compact subset of $\mathbb R$ to itself has a fixed point.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ be continuous. Then $f$ has at least a fixed point.

I read the following proof from Limaye book.

Define $F(x)=f(x)-x.$

Since $a \leq f(x) \leq b,\ \quad F(a)\leq 0 \ \quad \text{and}\ \quad  F(b)\geq 0.\longrightarrow *$

Since $F$ has intermediate value property, there is some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $F(c)=0.$

**Doubt:**

In this proof, I did not understand $*,\ i.e.,  F(a)\leq 0 \ \quad \text{and}\ \quad  F(b)\geq 0.$ I think that the inequalities should be reversed.

That is, since $a\leq f(a),\ F(a)\geq 0.$ Like that $F(b)\leq 0.$

Is this correct? Or Could someone please let me know how to understand this correctly?

Comment: The second set of inequalities look better to me, but this doesn't change the result.

Comment: You are correct and the book wrong.

Comment: @Michael Burr Though it does not change the result, i intend to know whether i have missed anything.

Comment: What is the title and edition of the textbook, and what is the page number of the proof? There are three errata listings for different versions of "A Course in Calculus and Real Analysis" at http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~srg/acicara/.